# How to run multiple instances of a method

Tags: javascript, methods

Using p5js I am creating the image of a tree against a canvas.

I have a class called tree that has a method within it that creates the tree.
The idea is that for each instance the x-coordinates are different so as to create a "forest"

```
tree = {
    pos_x :800,
    pos_y :410,
    tree_scale:random(40,60),
    tree_scale_2:random(20,40),
    tree_scale_3:random(20,50),
    color:random(150,180),
    color_2:random(120,150),
    color_3:random(150,175),
    trunk_color:random(20,84),
    new_tree:function(p){
        for(var i = 0; i < trees_x.length; i++){
            //Trunk
            fill(107, tree.trunk_color, 7);
            rect(p,tree.pos_y,15,25);
            //Leaves
            fill(0,tree.color,0);
            ellipse(p +35,tree.pos_y -25,tree.tree_scale_2);
            
            fill(0,tree.color_2,0);
            ellipse(p +39,tree.pos_y -75,tree.tree_scale_2);
            fill(0,tree.color,0);
            ellipse(p -25,tree.pos_y -72,tree.tree_scale_3);
            fill(0,tree.color_3,0);
            ellipse(p +5,tree.pos_y -90,tree.tree_scale);
            ellipse(p -27,tree.pos_y -52,tree.tree_scale_3);
            ellipse(p +37,tree.pos_y -55,50);
            ellipse(p +7,tree.pos_y -15,50);
            ellipse(p -27,tree.pos_y -25,40);
            ellipse(p +7,tree.pos_y -55,60);
        }
    }
```

I use this to assign the tree a random x-coordinate

```
loc = 1500;
    p = random(loc);
```

At the moment I am creating 2 trees, but they are the "Same" tree. What I'm looking for is for the method to each time return a different tree with different x coordinates.

```
tree.new_tree(p);
tree.new_tree(p);
```

Comment: I would double-check that the function actually is only running once.  A glance at the code makes me think it only appears to run once because it's drawing twice in the same place.

Comment: Check the result of `random(loc)`